# Why java floating point literal can not promote to double while I do the same with wrapper class?

Tags: java, wrapper, literals

```
float num1 = 1.0;
```

This code does not compile because floating-point numbers are default double and it can not be assigned to smaller types unless explicitly casting.

```
Float num2 = new Float(2.0);
```

But this code is compiled perfectly even 2.0 is a double literal. Can anyone explain to me what is happening for the second sample?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Class `Float`, you immediately get the answer:

```
public Float(double value) {
    this.value = (float)value;
}
```

btw you do need to do `Float num2 = new Float(2.0);`, `Float num2 = 2.0f;` is enough.